# Send form by POST method to another PHP file in Wix

Tags: forms, post, velo

How can I send form to another PHP file by POST method in Wix editor?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [fetch()](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-fetch.html#) function. Set the method to `"POST"` using the `options` parameter.